# Not able to display initial data from server using provider

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I am trying to display some initial data that gets pulled from a server in my app, I get the data but I am not able to display it. Here is my code please help

**Class where data has to be displayed**

```
import 'package:deep_pocket/models/data_feed.dart';
import 'package:deep_pocket/models/mock_data.dart';
import 'package:deep_pocket/widgets/menu_buttons.dart';
import 'package:deep_pocket/widgets/post_widget.dart';
import 'package:deep_pocket/screens/user_input.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class feedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/feed-screen';

  @override
  State<feedScreen> createState() => _feedScreenState();
}

class _feedScreenState extends State<feedScreen> {
  int filter = 0;
  var _intstate = true;

  void updateFilter(tx, context) {
    setState(() {
      filter = tx;
    });

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_intstate) {
      Provider.of<mockData>(context).fetchandAddPost();
    }
    _intstate = false;
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void filterSheet(ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (ctx) => Container(
              height: 300,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                height: 280,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: Tag.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            return updateFilter(i, context);
                          },
                          child: Text(Tag[i]),
                        )),
              )),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<mockData>(
        create: (context) => mockData(),
        builder: (context, child) {
          var posts = context.select((mockData m) => m.items);
          print(posts.length);
          if (filter != 0) {
            posts = posts.where((i) => i.tag == filter).toList();
          }
          return Scaffold(
            // drawer: Drawer(
            //     // Populate the Drawer in the next step.
            //     ),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Home"),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => {filterSheet(context)},
                    child: const Text(
                      "Filters",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  menuButtons(),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: posts.length,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => postWidget(post: posts[i])),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  //Waiting for result
                  var newData =
                      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, userInput.route);
                  if (newData != null) {
                    context.read<mockData>().addPost(newData as dataFeed);
                  }
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**Class where I have my Provider and fetch setup**

```
import 'package:deep_pocket/models/data_feed.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class mockData with ChangeNotifier {
  List<dataFeed> _data = [
    // dataFeed(
    //   id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    //   imgsrc: "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=a042581f4e29026704d",
    //   name: "Priyam Srivastava",
    //   title: "How to change room ?",
    //   tag: 1,
    //   text:
    // "I would like to know the process of changing my room cause I have not been able to study, and my roomate always plays music and drinks too much then shouts all night, please tell me how",
    // ),
    // dataFeed(
    //   id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    //   imgsrc: "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=a042581f4e29026704d",
    //   title: "Anyone intresed in playing BGMI?",
    //   name: "Part Agarwal",
    //   tag: 2,
    //   text:
    //       "So I have been looing for a squad for a long time and now i have finally decided that I am gonna buckle up and ask you all to join me",
    // ),
    // dataFeed(
    //   id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    //   imgsrc: "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=a042581f4e29026704d",
    //   title: "How to solve this question in O(n) complexity",
    //   name: "Preet Singh",
    //   tag: 3,
    //   text:
    //       "So I have been looing for a squad for a long time and now i have finally decided that I am gonna buckle up and ask you all to join me",
    // ),
  ];
  List<dataFeed> get items {
    return [..._data];
  }

  Future<void> fetchandAddPost() async {
    var url = link;
    try {
      print("getting your data");
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      final List<dataFeed> loadedPosts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
        loadedPosts.add(dataFeed(
            id: key,
            imgsrc: value['imgsrc'],
            name: value['name'],
            title: value['title'],
            text: value['text'],
            date: value['date']));
      });
      print(loadedPosts.length);
      _data = loadedPosts;
      print(_data.length);
      print("got your data");
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      // TODO
    }
  }

  Future<void> addPost(dataFeed newpost) async {
    var url = link;
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url as Uri,
        body: json.encode({
          'imgsrc': newpost.imgsrc,
          'name': newpost.name,
          'title': newpost.title,
          'text': newpost.text,
          'tag': newpost.tag,
          'date': newpost.date,
        }),
      );
      final newPost = dataFeed(
          id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
          imgsrc: newpost.imgsrc,
          name: newpost.name,
          title: newpost.title,
          text: newpost.text,
          tag: newpost.tag,
          date: newpost.date);
      _data.insert(0, newPost);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting data from server but it isn't being displayed, if I add new data it gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic use age for using `Provider`, fetch data from network, updating `ListView` and `pagination`.

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ExampleChangeNotifier>(
      create: (_) => ExampleChangeNotifier.instance(),
      builder: (_, child) {
        return Selector<ExampleChangeNotifier, NetworkStatus>(
          selector: (_, model) => model.networkStatus,
          builder: (_, nStatus, __) => nStatus == NetworkStatus.Loading
              ? const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : nStatus == NetworkStatus.Error
                  ? const Center(
                      child: Text('Your error widget'),
                    )
                  : Selector<ExampleChangeNotifier, int>(
                      selector: (_, model) => model.listLength,
                      builder: (_, length, __) => length > 0
                          ? ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: length + 1,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                if (index < length) {
                                  var listItem = _.read<ExampleChangeNotifier>().list[index];

                                  return SizedBox(
                                    height: 60,
                                    child: Text('List item: ${listItem.whatever}'),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Center(
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _.read<ExampleChangeNotifier>().loadMore();
                                      },
                                      child: Selector<ExampleChangeNotifier, bool>(
                                        selector: (_, model) => model.loadMoreRequest,
                                        builder: (_, value, __) => value ? const Text('loading...') : const Text('load more'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            )
                          : const Center(
                              child: Text('No data found'),
                            ),
                    ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

enum NetworkStatus { Loading, Done, Error }

class ExampleChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  NetworkStatus _networkStatus = NetworkStatus.Loading;
  NetworkStatus get networkStatus => _networkStatus;

  final List<dynamic> _list = <dynamic>[];
  List<dynamic> get list => _list;

  int _listLength = 0;
  int get listLength => _listLength;

  int _skip = 0; //Send this in your request parameters and use for pagination, e.g (for mysql query) => ... DESC LIMIT _skip, 10

  bool _loadMoreRequest = false;
  bool get loadMoreRequest => _loadMoreRequest;

  ExampleChangeNotifier.instance() {
    _getDataFromNetwork();
  }

  Future<void> _getDataFromNetwork() async {
    try {
      //Make your http request
      // For example : await http.get('https:example.com?skip=$_skip');
      _loadMoreRequest = false;
      // ... Parse your data
      List<dynamic> networkData = <dynamic>[];

      _networkStatus = NetworkStatus.Done;

      if (networkData.isNotEmpty) {
        for (var item in networkData) {
          _list.add(item);
          _listLength++;
        }
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
     _loadMoreRequest = false;
      _networkStatus = NetworkStatus.Error;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadMore() async {
    _skip = _listLength;
    _loadMoreRequest = true;
    notifyListeners();
    await _getDataFromNetwork();
  }
}
```